# How to bring forward all the extra fields value to another page

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can I bring all the values from addition fields to another page? currently it can only bring the first input text fields value only.

Example to test: 
Add extra 3 input text fields
 
First text field : 123
Second text field : 456
Third text field : 789
After filled up all the value and then click add, In next page show only 123 instead of 123,456,789

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/eR22N/

After click on add button it will link to this jsp -> "riskFactorSetup_rep.jsp".

```
    String field        = common.setNullToString(request.getParameter("field[]"));
    System.err.println("field==="+field);
```

After that I check at console it only show number 123.

Appreciate for help. Thank